# understanding Possible null reference return

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types, c#-9.0

I started to get these warnings with VS19 preview and

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>`
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Here is a sample from a class that proxy a lot of it's methods to `ImmutableList<T>`:

```
class C<T> {
  readonly ImmutableList<T> composed;
  public C() => composed = ImmutableList<T>.Empty;
  ...
  public T Find(Predicate<T> match) => composed.Find(match);
  ...
}
```

> warning CS8603: Possible null reference return.
> for the `Find` method

I don't understand why as it has the same signature as `ImmutableList<T>.Find` ?
What is the best way to resolve this ?

Comment: maybe try `.First()`?

Comment: @zaitsman That will solve the issue, but introduce the possibility of an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's described in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1.find?view=netcore-3.1)

> Returns
>
> The first element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, if found; otherwise, the default value for type T.

So return `T?` or maybe use `??` for returning a non null value.

About the same signature, in the code you could see this:

```
[return: MaybeNull]
public T Find(Predicate<T> match)
```

See [the code on github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/65c9be6388a99739bd72dc2136f4a0a59b00db72/src/libraries/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableList_1.cs#L596-L597)

And the [docs for [MaybeNull]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.maybenullattribute?view=netcore-3.1)

> Specifies that an output may be null even if the corresponding type disallows it.

Comment: So how does ImmutableList<T> gets away with exactly the same signature ? that is what confuses me

Comment: @kofifus Because it doesn't promise not to return `null` - but you _are_ promising not to return `null` (since you are using `T` in a class that says it is supporting nullable reference types).

Comment: "it doesn't promise not to return null" - where ? does that mean it does not have nullable enable ?

Comment: Correct - that is what it means. `ImmutableList` was built _prior_ to nullable reference types. So it doesn't promise not to return `null` (plus, why would it (even if it _was_ enabled)? it needs to indicate "I couldn't find anything" _somehow_ - how would you do it _without_ `null`?).

Answer (score 0):

The [Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1.find?view=net-5.0) will return default(T) when no match, which is null when T is a reference type. If you want to prevent that, you could [constrain your class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to only allow value types, for example.