# possible null reference return c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this linq query. It complains with the warning message.

> Warning CS8603: Possible null reference return

Code:

```
return await _applicationDbContext.Pies
                .Include(x => x.Portions).AsSingleQuery()
                .Include(x => x.Ingredients).AsSplitQuery()
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

Further more this is making it ugly with squiggles all over.

Can anything be done about it?

[image: Vs 2022 Warning message]

Looked at the following SO posts, but could not figure out what to do.

- [understanding Possible null reference return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63145379/1977871)
- [Understanding the new nullable reference types warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66265407/1977871)

Comment: What do you want your method to return if there is 0 or more than 1 pies?

Comment: It is not just a case of changing the method to return `Task<Pie?>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SingleOrDefaultAsync()` does exactly what's in the method name, it tries to find a single entry and returns the default if nothing is found.

The default for a reference type, your object `Pie` in this case, is null hence the warning.

You can either return `Task<Pie?>` or instead handle the null value in some way. One way would be to use `.SingleAsync()` instead, which will throw if nothing was found - but therefore it will never return null.

Answer (score 5):

The method returns a `Task<Pie>`.

The `return ...` has `SingleOrDefaultAsync(...)` at the end which means if it cannot find an item with a matching `id` it will return `default(Pie)` which will be `null`.

You need to decide if either:

1. This method can return null, then change the signature to `Task<Pie?>` to let calling code know that it can return null.
2. This method shouldn't return null, use `SingleAsync(...)` so that it will throw a runtime exception if no matching `id` is found.